# How to test Configuration Change with Espresso 2.0

Tags: android, testing, robolectric, android-espresso

I'm not really sure if it is event relevant, but I have a relatively complex custom `View`s and errors resulted by configuration changes pops up and I would definitely like to write tests for those and future cases.

Currently I'm using `Robolectric` for unit tests and with 1.1.0 `AS` started to use `Espresso` for UI tests. `Espresso` looks like a good candidate for such kind of testing. I run through docs and didn't find any hints on how to do that. Any experience to share? Thanks!

Comment: So less informations and it depends so much on your project configuration. Do you handle some change events self? The simplest way is to just call `onConfigurationChanged` method. But if you have some typical ui thread / background thread timing issues then this would not show them. So next approach is to rotate the screen which could be done with `activity.setRequestedOrientation`

Comment: What you are looking for appears to be here. https://gist.github.com/nbarraille/03e8910dc1d415ed9740

Answer (score 5):

It might be a little late but I found the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/nbarraille/03e8910dc1d415ed9740).

The class implements the `ViewAction` interface and in the `perform(...)` callback `activity.setRequestedOrientation(orientation);` is called. Please have a look at the gist :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is not possible with Espresso. Here is a look at the cheat sheet which suggests no such action in the API.

[image: Espresso Cheat Sheet]

I think what you would really want to do is use Robotium and specifically the method http://robotium.googlecode.com/svn/doc/com/robotium/solo/Solo.html#setActivityOrientation(int)

which allows you to use a `Solo` object to change orientation then you can group this with an assert type of test on your views.

Comment: Why use robotium when you can call `activity.setRequestedOrientation`?

Comment: @nenick Robotium provides a very nice wrapper to regular junits and let's you do Activity testing automatically. Calling activity.setRequestedOrientation may be accomplishing the same thing but its not using the testing framework to do the operation.

Comment: All those listed methods are just convenience wrappers around normal Android operations, so writing your own `ViewAction` that calls `setRequestedOrientation` is a solution "using Espresso".